# Cruise Control: Is it possible to create new projects from new SVN projects automatically

Tags: svn, automation, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol

I have just started thinking about migrating to cruise control from a personal tool.
I am using SVN and I have a structure like this :

```
svn
  projects
    project1
    project2
    ...
    projectn
  libs
    lib1
    lib2
    ...
    libn
  system
  prototypes
```

For now,

- I use sparse directories to navigate in the SVN structure (svn up -N svn/projects/project1) and when there is a final node with Trunk or Tags or Branches, I update the tree recursively (svn up svn/projects/project1/Trunk).
- I have succeeded in creating svn build with new build.xml + main config.xml file tuning for each of my projects.

Ideally, since all my build steps are identical (cd svn/projects/project1/Trunk && make all unit), I would like to automate the Cruise Control build step.
So I was still wondering 2 things:

1. Is there any way to avoid the step of creating a new build.xml + main config.xml file tuning for each of my projects. For example, to tell cruise crontrol one for all to use a template build.xml since all my builds consist in calling 'make' and 'make unit' commands + a generic regular regexp in main config.xml, such as svn/(projects|libs)/(.*)/(Trunk|Tags|Branches).
2. Would that be possible to display all these projects in a tree view in cruise control dashboard so that it is easier to link to the SVN repo ?

I keep on searching but if you have any piece of advice on how to do that, it would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.-> you can use template  and define preprocessor element that   . after you  have to replace all define value through a software that parse xml :

```
<cb:define mylabel="labelIwant"/>
```

2.->you can customize ccnet by modifing source but it will be hard as for me. Prefer perharps to use security permission and viewProject to enable to view some project according a role

```
 <rolePermission ..>
```